# Converting dictionary values only to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
myDict = [{'Type': 'Type1',
          'Value': 'A'},
          {'Type': 'Type2',
           'Value': 'B'}
         ]
```

And I'm trying to build a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Type1   Type2
  A       B
```

This feels like it should be straight forward but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the dict before you use it:

```
modified_dict = dict(d.values() for d in myDict)
df = pd.DataFrame(modified_dict, index=[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Type1 Type2
0     A     B
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dictionaries, where the values can be either columns or data. Based on the structure you provided, I made this solution using list comprehension.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(myDict[i].values())[1] for i in range(len(myDict))],
                  [list(myDict[i].values())[0] for i in range(len(myDict))]).T
```

The dataframe will look like the table below.

|  | Type1 | Type2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | B |

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Series as output you could use:

```
(pd.DataFrame(myDict)
   .set_index('Type')['Value']
 )
```

Output:

```
Type
Type1    A
Type2    B
Name: Value, dtype: object
```

For a DataFrame:

```
(pd.DataFrame(myDict)
   .set_index('Type')['Value']
   .to_frame().T
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
 )
```

Output:

```
      Type1 Type2
Value     A     B
```